# Every npm install gives "npm ERR! Only absolute URLs are supported"

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, npm-install

Tried nodeJS 8.12 and 10.11
Running latest npm 6.4.1

When trying to install any package i.e. (`npm install -g firebase-tools`) I get `npm ERR! Only absolute URLs are supported.`

Uninstalled and reinstall nodeJS. Still broken. Any help appreciated.

Debug Log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'firebase-tools' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.11.0
4 verbose npm-session 442f99e3eed77ef2
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for firebase-tools@latest Only absolute URLs are supported
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 206ms
10 verbose stack TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
10 verbose stack     at getNodeRequestOptions (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\request.js:131:11)
10 verbose stack     at fetch.Promise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:44:21)
10 verbose stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
10 verbose stack     at fetch (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:41:10)
10 verbose stack     at retry (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\index.js:332:14)
10 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-retry\index.js:29:24
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\Mine
12 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
13 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "firebase-tools"
14 verbose node v10.11.0
15 verbose npm  v6.4.1
16 error Only absolute URLs are supported
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263305/npm-package-not-found-but-found-on-website

Comment: it helped to find where the issue comes from! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@StevePerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9982761)'s question post.

> Had to edit `.npmrc` file located at `C:\Users\yourName\.npmrc`
>
> It had a bunch of lines. Only ones needed for me:
>
> ```
> //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken="your_auth_token"
> scope="your_name"
> @"your_name":registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
> ```