# Getting an error trying to install sinon that @sinonjs/commons not found with the phrase "name can only contain URL-friendly characters"

Tags: node.js, npm, sinon

I am trying to install sinon and I'm getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! 404  '@sinonjs/commons@^1.3.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can only contain URL-friendly characters
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'sinon'
```

Node version: 10.15.1

NPM version: 6.8.0

I tried running:

> npm install --save-dev sinon

I have checked my NPM registry is https://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: What's your npm version? I just tried and it works fine on 5.6.0.

Comment: @Phix It's 6.8.0

Answer (score 0):

I followed the solution found here: [NPM Package not found but found on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263305/npm-package-not-found-but-found-on-website)

It seems like my ~/.npmrc file had authentication information, but I don't have an account on https://registry.npmjs.org/