# Error when I run npm install Error: 404 Not Found: 7zip-bin@~4.1.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

When I run npm install I see this error

```
3 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: 7zip-bin@~4.1.0
2293 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\cygwin64\home\licbuild\ANSYSDev\LicensingPortal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
2293 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\cygwin64\home\licbuild\ANSYSDev\LicensingPortal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
2293 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\cygwin64\home\licbuild\ANSYSDev\LicensingPortal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
2293 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\cygwin64\home\licbuild\ANSYSDev\LicensingPortal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
2293 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\cygwin64\home\licbuild\ANSYSDev\LicensingPortal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
2293 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\cygwin64\home\licbuild\ANSYSDev\LicensingPortal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
2293 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\cygwin64\home\licbuild\ANSYSDev\LicensingPortal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
2293 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\cygwin64\home\licbuild\ANSYSDev\LicensingPortal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
2293 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\cygwin64\home\licbuild\ANSYSDev\LicensingPortal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
2293 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
2293 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
2293 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
```

As workaround I tried

1. npm i 7zip-bin@4.1.0, this didn't solve this issue
2. npm install https://npmjs.org/7zip-bin/v/4.1.0

This is npm repo for this package [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/7zip-bin/v/4.1.0)

Has anyone seen this kind of error before? Any suggestion will really be appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Try `npm install https://www.npmjs.com/package/7zip-bin/v/4.1.0`

Comment: When I ran npm install https://www.npmjs.com/package/7zip-bin/v/4.1.0

Comment: npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: https://www.npmjs.com/package/7zip-bin/v/4.1.0.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

Comment: I use node - 8.12.0 and npm 6.4.1

Comment: Had the same error, I just updated npm `npm install -g npm@latest` and works fine

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a transient issue as of today. I'm the maintainer of `error-ex` which has also received a report outlining this same issue from multiple users. The package exists and your registry string is correct - I believe they're having platform issues.

If you have a VPN, try to get close to California - apparently users around San Jose are able to get otherwise broken packages right now.

I have notified npm as I believe this to be an issue on their end.

EDIT: this has been fixed.

Comment: Are there any temporary solutions to this?

Comment: Installing directly from the git repository or using a public npm mirror as your registry string.

Comment: I downloaded https://registry.npmjs.org/7zip-bin/-/7zip-bin-4.1.0.tgz into node_modules of working directory and ran npm install, still I see this issue

Comment: I didn't get this point "Installing directly from the git repository or using a public npm mirror as your registry string"

Comment: @karansys try again now. They fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command first and then run yours:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

Comment: Hi, I still see same issue, I ran npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org and then npm install

Comment: I've found a similar question which might help your situation. Please check answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49263305/10556089

Comment: Thanks Shashvat Gupta, I followed same steps but this hasn't resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with npm, try fix by:

```
npm install -g npm
npm cache clean
npm update
npm install
```